# All support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I getting  alll support  libraries  must use  the  same  exact  version.
but I'm using the  same  version.

The  error i'm getting.

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 24.2.1, 23.0.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.2.1 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1 less...

My Build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0'



compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile files('libs/zxing-2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
//Citrus
compile 'com.citruspay.sdk:payment-sdk:4.1.3'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.2'
compile project(':qrpaylib')
}
```

can  you  help  me  in  this  scenario?

Comment: can you show add a screenshot of the error

Comment: I have  updated..Please check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: I'm also getting these errors after having updated Android Sudio to V2.3.2 I've read the linked question many time but it doesn't really give me an answer.  Did you managed to get this resolved @KartiikeyaBaleneni?